# Multi-row blog list in Jekyll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll

I want to use Jekyll & Bootstrap 3 to present my blog posts in a listing that looks like this:

[image: Columned blog post]

See how the posts are columnized with 2 per row? Can this same effect be acheived with Liquid and Bootstrap 3's grid system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are actually two questions.

### Number one: How to display two posts in each row with Jekyll/Liquid?

I answered two similar questions yesterday:

- [For loop, wrap every two posts in a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924471/for-loop-wrap-every-two-posts-in-a-div/20957689#20957689)
  *(one solution for a fixed number of posts - like the last 10 posts in groups of two on the front page - and one solution for an infinite number of posts)*
- [Jekyll automatically processing rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924701/jekyll-automatically-processing-rows/20958473#20958473)
  *(another solution with an infinite number of posts, but with four posts per group and with a detailed step-by-step explanation)*

### Number two: How to achieve a design similar to the one in your screenshot in Bootstrap?

Bootstrap has [a page with example designs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) that you can steal. Especially these two:

- [Jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/)
- [Narrow jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/)

Look at the source code of the example pages - basically, you just have to wrap the posts in a few `<div>`s with the right classes.

For example, this is the source code for the three blocks in the Jumbotron example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>blah</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>blah</p>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You just need to modify the code examples from my other answers *(linked above)* so that they generate a similar combination of `<div>`s.

Plus, you may want to read about [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to get the columns right *(e.g. the class `col-md-4` in the example code above varies depending on the number of columns you want)*.

---

Finally, a real-world example: [My blog](http://christianspecht.de/) has a similar listing on the front page.
This is a fixed number of posts *(the last nine, three rows of three)*, so I'm using the first approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957689/6884).
[The source code of the front page is here](https://bitbucket.org/christianspecht/blog/src/bc30ecf9205d3e8814bf76915bdcaee6956f055e/src/index.html?at=default).
**Note that I'm still on Bootstrap *2* (not 3), so you can't just copy and paste the CSS classes from my source code!**

Comment: Thanks for how thorough this answer is. I knew how to make columns in Bootstrap 3, but I didn't know how to apply it via Jekyll. So technically, I meant this as one question, but this will help those unfamiliar with Bootstrap's grid immensely. Once again, thanks a ton! I will test this out and be sure to confirm your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have designed a theme for Jekyll using the Bootstrap 3. I know a lot of people want the column feature of bootstrap.

Check out [this sample post](http://hmfaysal.github.io/hmfaysal-omega-theme/sample-posts/fancy-columns/) from my theme showing example column configurations.

Answer (score 1):

**An example with explanation that uses four columns:**

```
<div class="container">

    {% for post in site.posts %}

        {% cycle 'add row' : '<div class="row">', nil, nil, nil %}

            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <!-- liquid tags here -->
            </div>

        {% cycle 'end row' : nil, nil, nil, '</div>' %}

    {% endfor %}
    {% cycle 'end row' : nil, '</div>', '</div>', '</div>' %}

</div>
```

Consider the first cycle. The first and every fourth iteration through the loop, a new row div is added. The rest of the time nothing happens because of the `nil` arguments.

```
{% cycle 'add row' : '<div class="row">', nil, nil, nil %}
```

Consider the second cycle. Every fourth iteration through the loop the row div is closed. The other iterations pass through `nil` and nothing happens.

```
{% cycle 'end row' : nil, nil, nil, '</div>' %}
```

Consider the third cycle. This uses the same `end row` identifier as the previous cycle, so it follows the same order. The point is to close the last row except in the case when the previous cycle handles it.

```
{% cycle 'end row' : nil, '</div>', '</div>', '</div>' %}
```

Finally, to get the right number of columns with Bootstrap, use the appropriate cell class. I used `.col-sm-3` to get four columns (12/3) to display on desktops and tablets but not phones.

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

**For three columns, use:**

```
{% cycle 'add row' : '<div class="row">', nil, nil %}
{% cycle 'end row' : nil, nil, '</div>' %}
{% cycle 'end row' : nil, '</div>', '</div>' %}
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
```

**For two columns, use:**

```
{% cycle 'add row' : '<div class="row">', nil %}
{% cycle 'end row' : nil, '</div>' %}
{% cycle 'end row' : nil, '</div>' %}
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in place on a jekyll project displaying posts in a Bootstrap grid, and it works great:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <ul>
            {% for product in site.pages %}
            {% if product.sub-category == 'sample-category' %}

            <li>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                        <img src="{{ product.img }}" />
                        <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
                        <h4>{{ product.part_number }}</h4>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>

            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```